# joining two strings with Malloc

Tags: c

I have been working through a beginner C problem to try and learn the basics of C. I noticed the problem below will start at the index of where the last string takes off and will finish that string, but what I'm trying to do is join the two strings together.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I'm trying to do this without realloc for learning xp.

```
char *string_dup(char *src)
{
  int len = strlen(src);
  char *src2 = malloc(len + 1);
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    *(src2 + i) = *(src + i);
  }
  *(src2 + len )='\0';
  return src2;
}

void *resize_memory(void *ptr, int old_size, int new_size)
{
    char *d = (char*)ptr;
    d = malloc(new_size);
}


char *url = string_dup("http://");
char *path = string_dup("website.com/");
int url_length = string_length(url);
int path_length = string_length(path);

int new_length = url_length - 1 + path_length;
char *new_url = resize_memory(url, url_length, new_length);
char *p = new_url + url_length;


while (*path != '\0') {
    *p = *path;
    p++;
    path++;
}

printf("Full path string: %s\n", new_url);
```

Comment: Is the exercise here to re-implement `strdup`? Just want to understand the goal.

Comment: Note: It's conventional to use `size_t` instead of `int` for lengths. This is an unsigned integer as obviously negative sizes don't make sense.

Comment: It also looks like you need to turn on way more warnings, even `-Wall`, as your `resize_memory` function does not return anything, yet promises to return `void*`. This code can't work until you `return d`.

Comment: Remember to free that memory!

Comment: `resize_memory` should probably also copy the old buffer into the new one.

Comment: Ask yourself what exactly you want. I think you need a `char *join(const char *s, const char *t)`which allocates `strlen(s) + strlen(t) + 1` then copies `s` (minus null) and `t` into the buffer, perhaps using `memcpy`.

Comment: oh I know its a beginner problem for C. I'm a beginner.

Comment: @chargerfan619 Are you looking to write a new function or modify one of the existing functions you posted here?

Comment: I'm trying to get printf("Full path string: %s\n", new_url); to equal "http:// website.com/" by modifying resize_memory function

Comment: OK, strlen(const char*) is a library function, but what is string_length(char*)?

Comment: The function resize_memory does not pass back anything.
Either you may want to change the return value from void to char* or you want to use a double pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Trouble with OP's code:

**Wrong size**

Assuming `string_length()` is like `strlen()`.

```
// int new_length = url_length - 1 + path_length;
int new_length = url_length + 1 + path_length;
```

**Ineffective resize**

```
void *resize_memory(void *ptr, int old_size, int new_size) {
    char *d = (char*)ptr; // assign `d`
    d = malloc(new_size); // Why re-assigned `d`???
    // No use of old_size, new_size
    // No copying of existing data 
    // No freeing of old allocation  
}
```

I'd expect something like

```
// return failure status
bool resize_memory(void **ptr_addr, size_t old_size, size_t new_size) {
  void *new_ptr = NULL;
  if (new_size > 0) {
    new_ptr = malloc(new_size);
    if (new_ptr) {  // Out of memory, leave *ptr_addr alone
      return true;
    }
    size_t min_size = old_size < new_size ? old_size : new_size;
    memcpy(new_ptr, *ptr_addr, min_size);
  }
  free(*ptr_addr);
  *ptr_addr = new_ptr;  
  return false;
}
```

---

Ways to join strings with `realloc()` with allocation.

1. Find lengths.
2. Allocate memory.
3. If successful, copy the first and then the second string.  Append a \0.

Sample code:

```
// s1, s2 may be NULL.  A NULL is treated as if ""
char *JoinStrings(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  size_t len1 = s1 ? strlen(s1) : 0;
  size_t len2 = s2 ? strlen(s2) : 0;
  char *joined = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
  if (joined) {
    memcpy(joined, s1, len1);
    memcpy(joined + len1, s2, len2);
    joined[len1 + len2] = '\0';
  }
  return joined;
}
```

Or via `snprintf()`

```
char *JoinStrings(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  size_t sz = (s1 ? strlen(s1) : 0) + (s2 ? strlen(s2) : 0) + 1;
  char *joined = malloc(sz);
  if (joined) {
    int len = snprintf(joined, sz, "%s%s", s1, s2);
    assert(len >= 0 && (unsigned) len < sz);  // Failure is very unexpected here.
  }
  return joined;
}
```

To concatenate like (*s1) += s2

```
// *s1 is a prior allocated string, or NULL
 void ConcatenateString(char **s1, const char *s2) {
  char *joined = JoinStrings(*s1, s2);
  free(*s1);
  *s1 = joined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
char *url = string_dup("http://");
char *path = string_dup("website.com/");
size_t sTotal = strlen(url) + strlen(path) + 1u;
char *pStr = malloc(sTotal);
snprintf(pStr, sTotal, "%s%s", url, path);
free(url);
free(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I played about with your code for a bit then came up with this solution. This allows you to get rid of that  `string_dup()` function and create a single function that can allocate/assign a new string and append an existing string with more data.

```
int
append_string(char **append_to, char *append_this) {
    char    *tmp;

    // You might want to check that append_this is not
    // NULL...

    if (*append_to == NULL) {
        *append_to = malloc(strlen(append_this) + 1);
        strcpy(*append_to, append_this);
    }
    else {
        // Some data already exists on the append_to buffer...
        //
        // If you want to only use malloc() then make a temporary
        // storage area and copy the append_to string there
        //
        if ((tmp = malloc(strlen(*append_to) + 1)) == NULL)
            return -1;
        strcpy(tmp, *append_to);

        // Free up and re-allocate append_to.
        //
        free(*append_to);
        *append_to = malloc(strlen(tmp) + strlen(append_this) + 1);

        if (! append_to) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Malloc error...");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Do it with realloc
        //
        // No temporary buffer required:
        //
        //      *append_to = realloc(
        //          *append_to,
        //          (strlen(append_to) + strlen(*append_this) + 1)
        //      );
        //      if (! eppend_to) ...realloc error

        // Copy the data to the buffer and clean up.
        //
        sprintf(*append_to, "%s%s", tmp, append_this);
        free(tmp);
    }
}


/* In your main() or whatever... */

    char *url = NULL;
    char *path = NULL;

    // Since url and path are both NULL the
    // append string function will act like
    // your string_dup() function...
    append_string(&url, "http://");
    append_string(&path, "website.com/");

    // And not that url is not null it will be
    // resized and the path appended.
    append_string(&url, path);

    fprintf(stdout, "URL: %s\n", url);

    // Some housekeeping....
    if (url) free(url);
    if (path) free(path);
}
```

Hope it's useful, I know it's kinda way off from what you originally had but thought I'd play along!